# Redirect cache is stuck in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, redirect

I've disabled caching when the dev tools are open but it is still redirecting me to a page I accidentally set as a 301 redirect when testing some code. Now I can't get to the correct page because Chrome always assumes I'm trying to get to the original page I redirected to when I was testing.

For instance, I setup a test redirect from `http://example.dev/page-1` to go to `http://example.dev/page-2` but that was accidental. I need it to actually load `http://example.dev/page-1` but every time it now takes me to `http://example.dev/page-2` which doesn't actually exist.

I've tried clearing the application cache as well and doing a hard reload on the site but those didn't work.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10):

Use of net-interals is deprecated and this answer no longer works.

This still does, though:

https://www.ryadel.com/en/clear-google-chrome-redirect-cache-for-single-url-page-howto/

1. List item
2. List item

Press SHIFT+CTRL+I to open the Google Chrome Developer Tools panel.

Go to the Network tab and select the Disable cache checkbox to enable that feature.

Type the URL you want to clear from the browser cache in the address bar and press Enter.

Click and hold the reload button until a modal window pops up, the select the Empty Cache and Hard Reload hidden option.

As soon as the page has been fully reloaded, you can unselect the Disable cache checkbox and disable that feature.

The Developer Tools panel must remain open for the whole process, otherwise Chrome won’t let you to use Empty Cache and Hard Reload feature.

Answer (score 8):

Chrome always cache page redirection. Try the following way to clear redirection cache.

1. Go to `chrome://net-internals/`
2. Clear cache with top right arrow option `Clear cache`
3. Try on your page again :)

hope this can help you